# Assistance with SQL query (need to add more columns and filters)

Tags: sql-server

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActivityList] 
(
    [ActivityListId]  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ActivityName]    NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive]        NVARCHAR (6)   NULL,
    [CreatedDate]     DATETIME2 (7)  NULL,
    [CreatedBy]       NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [UpdatedDate]     DATETIME2 (7)  NULL,
    [UpdatedBy]       NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [DeactivatedDate] DATETIME2 (7)  NULL,
    [DeactivatedBy]   NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [DepartmentId]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [SiteView]        VARCHAR (20)   DEFAULT ('Warehouse') NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ActivityListId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ActivityList_DepartmentId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([DepartmentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Department] ([DepartmentId])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Department] 
(
    [DepartmentId]    INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentName]  VARCHAR (30)  NOT NULL,
    [IsActive]        NVARCHAR (6)  NULL,
    [CreatedDate]     DATETIME2 (7) NULL,
    [CreatedBy]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [UpdatedDate]     DATETIME2 (7) NULL,
    [UpdatedBy]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [DeactivatedDate] DATETIME2 (7) NULL,
    [DeactivatedBy]   NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [SiteView]        VARCHAR (20)  DEFAULT ('Warehouse') NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DepartmentId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimeSheet] 
(
    [TimeSheetId]    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Week]           INT            NOT NULL,
    [Departmentname] NVARCHAR (30)  NOT NULL,
    [WorkDate]       DATE           NOT NULL,
    [Employee]       VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [Activity]       NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Time]           TIME (7)       NULL,
    [IsActive]       NVARCHAR (6)   NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate]    DATETIME2 (7)  NULL,
    [CreatedBy]      NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [UpdatedDate]    DATETIME2 (7)  NULL,
    [UpdatedBy]      NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [DeletedDate]    DATETIME2 (7)  NULL,
    [DeletedBy]      NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [UserId]         INT            NOT NULL,
    [ActivityListId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentId]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [Company]        NVARCHAR (16)  NULL,
    [Notes]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [SiteView]       VARCHAR (20)   DEFAULT ('Warehouse') NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TimeSheetId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_UserId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[users] ([UserId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ActivityListId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ActivityListId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ActivityList] ([ActivityListId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_DepartmentId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([DepartmentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Department] ([DepartmentId])
);
```

and a query that looks like this

```
WITH a AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ts.[week], 
        ts.departmentid, 
        ts.employee, 
        ts.company, 
        ts.activitylistid, 
        minutes_worked = COALESCE(Sum(Datediff(minute, '0:00:00', time)), 0) 
    FROM   
        timesheet ts 
    WHERE  
        createddate BETWEEN '01/01/2018' AND '12/31/2018' 
        AND siteview = 'Warehouse' 
    GROUP BY 
        ts.[week], 
        ts.departmentid, 
        ts.activitylistid, 
        ts.employee, 
        ts.company
) 
SELECT 
    d.departmentname, 
    al1.activityname, 
    COALESCE((SELECT CAST((minutes_worked / 60) AS VARCHAR(8)) + ':' 
                        + RIGHT('0' + CAST((minutes_worked % 60) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
              FROM a 
              WHERE a.activitylistid = al1.activitylistid 
                AND a.departmentid = al1.departmentid 
               AND week = 18), '00:00') Week_18 
FROM   
    activitylist al1 
INNER JOIN 
    department D ON al1.departmentid = d.departmentid 
WHERE  
    d.departmentid = 4 
ORDER BY 
    D.departmentid, 
    al1.activityname
```

With the query above I get the departmentname, ActivityName, and the total hours worked for each activity on the given week. Now, my question is, with the same query, is it possible to get the employee, company, and the created date? if so, can someone point in the right direction? Also, is it possible to provide multiple employees to the filter?

This is the output that I'm getting with the original query.

[image]

and this is the output that I get if I join the TimeSheet table.

I want the results to be shown as the first output but this the columns employe, company, and createddate added.

[image]

Comment: To add columns to the result, you add them to the list in the `SELECT` statement. (The second one that is halfway down) Try that first. To include multipile employees in the filter you can use `IN`. I suggest you start reading here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/ - it's a great resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just `JOIN` `TimeSheet` with `activityList` table in your final `SELECT`. This is assuming you have one record in `Timesheet` table for each `ActivityListId`. To filter by Employee just include it in `WHERE` clause.

```
WITH a
AS ( SELECT   ts.[week] ,
              ts.departmentid ,
              ts.employee ,
              ts.company ,
              ts.activitylistid ,
              minutes_worked = COALESCE(
                                   SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', time)), 0)
     FROM     timesheet ts
     WHERE    createddate
              BETWEEN '01/01/2018' AND '12/31/2018'
              AND siteview = 'Warehouse'
     GROUP BY ts.[week] ,
              ts.departmentid ,
              ts.activitylistid ,
              ts.employee ,
              ts.company )
SELECT   D.departmentname ,
         al1.activityname ,
         ts.employee ,
         ts.company ,
         ts.createddate ,
         COALESCE(
         (   SELECT CAST(( minutes_worked / 60 ) AS VARCHAR(8)) + ':'
                    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(( minutes_worked % 60 ) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
             FROM   a
             WHERE  a.activitylistid = al1.activitylistid
                    AND a.departmentid = al1.departmentid
                    AND week = 18 ) ,
         '00:00') Week_18
FROM     activitylist al1
         INNER JOIN department D ON al1.departmentid = D.departmentid
         INNER JOIN TimeSheet ts ON al1.ActivityListId = ts.ActivityListId
WHERE    D.departmentid = 4
ORDER BY D.departmentid ,
         al1.activityname;
```

**Update:** Updating query to provide distinct `company` and `employee` by filtering `Timesheet` based on `createddate`

```
WITH a
AS ( SELECT   ts.[week] ,
              ts.departmentid ,
              ts.employee ,
              ts.company ,
              ts.activitylistid ,
              minutes_worked = COALESCE(
                                   SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', time)), 0)
     FROM     timesheet ts
     WHERE    createddate
              BETWEEN '01/01/2018' AND '12/31/2018'
              AND siteview = 'Warehouse'
     GROUP BY ts.[week] ,
              ts.departmentid ,
              ts.activitylistid ,
              ts.employee ,
              ts.company )
SELECT   D.departmentname ,
         al1.activityname ,
         ts.Employee ,
         ts.Company ,
         --ts.createdDate ,
         COALESCE(
         (   SELECT CAST(( minutes_worked / 60 ) AS VARCHAR(8)) + ':'
                    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(( minutes_worked % 60 ) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
             FROM   a
             WHERE  a.activitylistid = al1.activitylistid
                    AND a.departmentid = al1.departmentid
                    AND week = 18 ) ,
         '00:00') Week_18
FROM     activitylist al1
         INNER JOIN department D ON al1.departmentid = D.departmentid
         INNER JOIN (   SELECT  DISTINCT ActivityListId ,
                                         Company ,
                                         Employee
                        FROM    timesheet
                        WHERE   createdDate
                        BETWEEN '20180601' AND '20180630' ) AS ts ON al1.ActivityListId = ts.ActivityListId
WHERE    D.departmentid = 4
ORDER BY D.departmentid ,
         al1.activityname;
```

Comment: Hi @AB_87, thanks for your answer. I've tried that approach before asking the question but the output is not what I've expected. For instance, with the provided query, all columns repeat the same values over and over. As for your assumption, not all the activities are on the TimeSheet table.

Comment: It will help people provide answer if you provide sample data and expected output. Repeating values suggest multiple rows in `Timesheet` for same ActivityListId. Also I see from tables you have provided that only `TimeSheet` table has `Employee` column. What is the expected result for Employee column if activity does not exist in `TimeSheet` table?

Comment: I don't expect anything if the activity name doesn't exist; I want each activity to be unique.

Comment: You are getting repeating values for various column because you have multiple records in `TimeSheet` table for each `AcitivtyListId`. But as you would have noticed, `CreateDate` is different. What `CreateDate` do you want in your final result if you don't want repeated values for other columns? Also, please add sample data in your question.

Comment: The createddate should display when the record was entered on the TimeSheet table. I'm trying to use this column to filter between the dates and display only the dates in the between filter.

Comment: Each Activity has multiple records in `TimeSheet` table and so multiple `createddate` values. I am not sure what you mean by "The createddate should display when the record was entered on the TimeSheet table". If you want to use `createddate` for filter, you can use it in where clause and return distinct `company` and `employee` from `TimeSheet`.

Comment: Please accept answer if it helped. I have updated answer as discussed.

Comment: Sure thing. Thank you!